# What is tabStyle equivalent for URL addressable Lightning components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I've got a component that overrides standard object. From it, user navigates to secondary component via URL (aka `implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable"`).

I want the previously active tab to stay highlighted.